# Problem optimizing sql query with cross apply sub query

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization

So I have three tables:

MakerParts, that holds the primary information of a Vehicle Part:

| Id | MakerId | PartNumber | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ABC1234 | Tire |
| 2 | 1 | XYZ1234 | Door |

`MakerPrices`, that holds the price history variation for the parts (references `MakerParts.Id` on `MakerPartNumberId`, and the table `MakerPriceUpdates` on `UpdateId`):

| Id | MakerPartNumberId | UpdateId | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 9.83 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 11.23 |

`MakerPriceUpdates`, that holds the date of prices updates. This update is basically a CSV file that is uploaded to our system. One file, one line on this table, multiple prices changes on the table `MakerPrices`.

| Id | Date | FileName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-09 00:00:00.000 | temp.csv |
| 2 | 2019-01-11 00:00:00.000 | temp2.csv |

---

This means that one part (MakerParts) may have multiple prices (MakerPrices). The date of the price change is on the table MakerPricesUpdates.

I want to **select all MakerParts where the most recent price is zero**, filtering by the MakerId on table MakerParts.

What I've tried:

```
select mp.* from MakerParts mp cross apply
    (select top 1 Price from MakerPrices inner join 
        MakerPricesUpdates on MakerPricesUpdates.Id = MakerPrices.UpdateId where 
        MakerPrices.MakerPartNumberId = mp.Id order by Date desc) as p
where mp.MakerId = 1 and p.Price = 0
```

But that is absurdly slow (we have about 100 million lines on the MakerPrices table). I'm having a hard time optimizing this query. (the result is only two rows for the MakerId 1, and it took 2 mins to run). I also tried:

```
select * from (
    select 
        mp.*,
        (select top 1 Price from MakerPrices inner join 
        MakerPricesUpdates on MakerPricesUpdates.Id = MakerPrices.UpdateId 
        where MakerPrices.MakerPartNumberId = mp.Id order by Date desc) as Price
    from MakerParts mp) as temp
where temp.Price = 0 and MakerId = 1
```

Same result, and same time. My query plan (for the first query) (no new indexes suggested by Management Studio):

[image]

Comment: Why it shouldnt be a inner join like below?  Will this not give you desired result? Please check. 


select mp.* from MakerParts mp join
    (select top 1 Price, MakerPartNumberId from MakerPrices inner join 
        MakerPricesUpdates on MakerPricesUpdates.Id = MakerPrices.UpdateId where 
        MakerPrices.MakerPartNumberId = mp.Id order by Date desc) as p
where mp.id = p.MakerPartNumberId  and mp.MakerId = 1 and p.Price = 0

Comment: This gives me `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'`. I'm using SQL Azure V12.

Comment: Changing the first `join` to `cross apply` works, but it is slow.

Comment: Please see the query for reference in the fiddle url. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18cd2de6ba669d9b92ce5bbdb255127b  

Thanks

Comment: @praveen thanks. I am getting zero rows as response. I believe that the inner `select top 1 * from MakerPricesUpdates order by Date desc` will always return the same update Id. That way, only the prices for the parts on the most recent update will be checked, and in this update there are a few MakerPrices updated and none with Price = 0

Comment: I've added some sample data and modified query in the below fiddle url. Please see if it helps.  Thanks

[Fiddle URL] : (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90a579360ad1b8c807e334d43f2534fb)

Comment: @praveen Thank you so much. Unfortunately, now I'm getting "any" part that ever has a price = 0. There are resulting parts in which the most up-to-date price is > 0, and they are selected because in the past one of the prices was zero. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid joining `MakerPriceUpdates` with `makerprices` since with the highest
`UpdateId` you can find the latest price updates. It will save you some time.

```
select mp.* from MakerParts mp cross apply
    (select top 1 Price from MakerPrices where 
        MakerPrices.MakerPartNumberId = mp.Id order by MakerPrices.UpdateId desc) as p
where mp.MakerId = 1 and p.Price = 0
```

You can further reduced some times by avoiding sort and order by with cte and row_number() as below:

```
;with LatestMakerPrices as
(
    select  *,row_number()over(partition by MakerPartNumberId order by updateid desc)rn from MakerPrices 
)
select mp.* from MakerParts mp cross apply
    (select price from LatestMakerPrices lmp where lmp.MakerPartNumberId=mp.Id) as p
where mp.MakerId = 1 and p.Price = 0
```

Execution plan difference between query in question and my answer:
[image]

Comment: Nice, the second query runs instantly! Unfortunately, ordering by the Date is mandatory, since the user can make an upload of a "old" CSV (they actually select the date in the UI). Is there anyway to use your second query ordering desc by date?

Comment: Please let me try first.

Comment: Of course! I need to sleep a bit, my head is killing me. I will come back to check tomorrow; no need to hurry. Thank you so much.

Comment: kindly discuss with me tomorrow at 3:00 P.M according to Pakistan time, I will write algorithm according to your needs  that will give you better performance @Guilherme

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
WITH tab AS (
    SELECT *, NULL as Price FROM MakerParts
    WHERE not exists ( 
        SELECT Id
        FROM MakerPrices
        WHERE MakerPrices.MakerPartNumberId = MakerParts.Id 
    )  
)

SELECT * from tab WHERE MakerId = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT a.* , Price
FROM [dbo].[MakerParts] a
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MakerPrices] b
    ON b.MakerPartNumberId = a.Id
WHERE MakerId = 2 AND Price = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is more than the expected two rows. In the extra ones, the most recent Price is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try your query:

```
select mp.* from MakerParts mp cross apply
    (select top 1 Price from MakerPrices inner join 
        MakerPricesUpdates on MakerPricesUpdates.Id = MakerPrices.UpdateId where 
        MakerPrices.MakerPartNumberId = mp.Id order by Date desc) as p
where mp.MakerId = 1 and p.Price = 0
```

After creating below index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIdx_MakerPrices_MakerPartNumberId_UpdateId] ON [dbo].[MakerPrices]
(
    [MakerPartNumberId] ASC,
    [UpdateId] ASC
)
INCLUDE([Price])
```

And making `ID` column of `MakerPricesUpdates` table primary key.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, now I'm getting "any" part that ever has a price = 0. There are resulting parts in which the most up-to-date price is > 0, and they are selected because in the past one of the prices was zero. Any more ideas?

Comment: Please share some sample data for betterunderstanding.

Comment: Make ID column of table MakerPricesUpdates  primary key (if not) and create  the index in the question and try to execute your query.